# Removing Lawmakers from Committee Assignments

Tags: united-states, congress

Marjory Taylor-Green was removed from her committee assignments because of things she said. I understand that what she said crossed a line. I also hear that what she said helped incite violence. However, aren't there others who have done the same thing? There were congressmen who were pro the black lives matter protests - which certainly caused more damage than those in the capitol.

Have other lawmakers been punished in this way for things they have said? Is the house or senate currently considering doing the same for any other representatives?

Comment: Could you state please what the question actually is, @Burt?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about being removed by a vote on the floor of the House?  Or would the party leadership removing them suffice?

Comment: @JoeC either one

Comment: The Capitol riots resulted in five deaths. The BLM protests, to the best of my knowledge, resulted in zero. I guess it depends on what you consider to be more valuable - property, which can be repaired, or human lives, which can't.

Comment: @F1Krazy https://www.forbes.com/sites/jemimamcevoy/2020/06/08/14-days-of-protests-19-dead/

Comment: Judging by the downvotes, I think your question is coming off as just trying to push an equivalency about what people said rather than a genuine question about 
when/how lawmakers have been punished for what they've said. I didn't want to make this big of an edit and potentially change what you're asking about, but I believe you could get rid of everything except your first two and last two sentences and people will no longer think it's a bad-faith/unclear question.

Comment: @Burt These are mostly just normal murders where the victims happened to have attended a protest, or murders that happened during times when there were protests. Of those 19: 1 was a police officer who was targeted (though the police were unsure if there was a connection to the protests), 4 were possible or suspected looters who were killed, 4 were cases where peaceful protesters were the _victims_ of attacks by counter-protesters, while 10 were murders completely unrelated to any protests.

Comment: @Divibisan if we're splitting hairs like that then only two of the deaths at the capitol should count.  One police officer was bludgeoned, and one woman was shot.  Two deaths were cardiovascular problems, strokes I think, and one was a fall with a head injury.

Comment: @Ryan_L Your argument is nonsensical. If we count every carjacking or liquor store robbery that happened to occur around the same time as a protest as a "death related to the protest", then should we count the 3000 Americans who died of COVID during the insurrection? It's just absurd.

Comment: If you're talking about deaths we can blame on the Capitol Insurrectionists, I'd say there are 4: [1 cop beaten to death, 1 rioter crushed to death](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2021/jan/08/capitol-attack-police-officer-five-deaths) and 2 cops [dead by suicide in the aftermath](https://www.politico.com/news/2021/01/27/second-officer-suicide-following-capitol-riot-463123)

Comment: @divibisan then we have to count every suicide related to damages caused by the protesting.  I was agreeing with you that we need to be careful what we count, I just want the same standard used on the capitol unrest.  I don't want to count the strokes during the capitol unrest any more than you want to count David Dorn's murder.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question after the OP had edited the original question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been downvoted enough times that it seems community wise it is not a good fit.

Comment: I think the big problem that people have with her statements is that she has appeared to call for the death of prominent Democrat officials by either liking them or suggesting that a plan is getting put in place in response to social media posts calling for such actions. That and crazy theories such as space lasers being responsible for the california fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it has happened before.

In January 2019, Representative Steve King (R-IA) was removed from his position on the Judiciary and Agriculture Committees by his party leadership after questioning why white supremacy is considered offensive.

[Source: New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/14/us/politics/steve-king-white-supremacy.html)